# Check Anchor Tag Text in a Loop for HoverJquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, anchor

Im stuck where i need to change the value of the text if the value of the text is "Joined" when it was hovered but i dont know why it always try to go on else that means it is false,

This is my Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.k-button').hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() == "Joined") {
            $this.data('initialText', $this.text());
            $this.text("Unjoin?");
        } else {
            $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
        }
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
    }
);
</script>
```

---

```
<td>@if (@item.IsJoined == "Joined")
                        {

                    <a href="/User/UnjoinEvent?EventId=@item.EventId&eventdateid=@item.EventDateId" id="btnDelete+@item.EventDateId" class="k-button" style="text-decoration: none;">
                             @item.IsJoined</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             <a href="/User/JoinEvent?eventId=@item.EventId&eventdateid=@item.EventDateId" id="btnEdits+@item.EventDateId" class="k-button" style="text-decoration: none; ">
                            @item.IsJoined</a>
                        }
                    </td>
```

This Html code is in a Table/GridView

Thanks to Someone Who can Help me

Comment: show your html structure

Comment: @Tyagi edited sir, The Html is in a Table or DataGrid

Comment: instead if $(this).text() , try $.trim($(this).html())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to trim the text. Here is the fix:

```
 <a href="#" class="k-button" style="text-decoration: none;">
                             Joined</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.k-button').hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().trim() == "Joined") {
            $this.data('initialText', $this.text());
            $this.text("Unjoin?");
        } else {
            $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
        }
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
    }
);
</script>
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/87RXZ/

Comment: Thanks for this and for the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use

> $(this).text().trim() == "Joined"

Or

> $(this).html().trim() == "Joined"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works : in case you are making 'td' dynamically :

```
$('a').on('hover','.k-button',function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().trim() == "Joined") {
            $this.data('initialText', $this.text());
            $this.text("Unjoin?");
        } else {
            $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use these code

```
jQuery( ".class" ).on({
    mouseenter:
    function()
    {
    //Some code
    },
    mouseleave:
    function()
    {
    //Some code
    }
});
```

These code will be works for multiple tag as you use while hover is works for only first tag
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kapil_dev/tLRX4/1/